# What are the benefits of a non-linear promotion/relegation system?

Tags: rugby, international-sports, promotions, relegations

In Italian rugby you can be promoted from III division (Serie A girone B) directly to I division (Eccellenza), and you can be relegated from II division (Serie A girone A) directly to IV division (Serie B).

Which are the benefits of such an odd format?

Is this format really odd, or is it somewhat widespread in team sports?

Comment: @edmastermind29 While here I'm trying a broader question and any team sports employing such a rule would fit, I again wonder why you specifically added [tag:uefa].

Comment: This was due to the Serie-A/B inclusion...but please accept my apologies as I overlooked the `rugby` tag. Since you were going broader, I did not feel `italy` was appropriate for either question. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @edmastermind29 nevermind, I'm perfectly fine with that! (good idea to remove [tag:italy], I'm wondering if it would be better to remove [tag:rugby], since I would accept answers on other team sports too.

Comment: Rugby's your main example, but added `international-sports` to include other team sports broadly.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly the most extreme system comes from Chess, and the McMahon competition format.

The idea behind big drops in those instances are to ensure that competitors are, as often as possible, meeting evenly matched competitors.

How often large adjustments in seeding, ranking and match-pairing are made in team sports, I cannot say.